# Importrange Function with Condition to remove Special Character

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, importrange

I have a Google sheet Data table with data which looks like this

```
<0.03
<0.03
<0.03
<0.03
<0.03
<0.03
0.04
0.03
<0.03
<0.03
<0.03
```

I want to import this data into another google sheet but also remove the special character `<`

Expected result is

```
0.03
0.03
0.03
0.03
0.03
0.03
0.04
0.03
0.03
0.03
0.03
```

if the `Importrange` formula goes by

```
=importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RstSwZGiTzKDdEy8D0zxz2sczr1Bnf4_0-CbpM_Po0/edit?ts=5ccaa041#gid=xxxxxxxx","Sheet1!D4:D")
```

What conditional filter should I use to remove the `<` special character? I understand that I need to use a `Query` Function with the `importrange`. But not sure on the condition to use to remove the `<` special character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT( 
 IMPORTRANGE("ID", "Sheet2!A1:A")), "\d+.*"))), VALUE(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT( 
 IMPORTRANGE("ID", "Sheet2!A1:A")), "\d+.*"))),))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Does this formula convert my data into text?.. i need to do other manipulations with my data like find the min max mean. Currently the min max mean functions identify this data value to be 0. this data serves as a data source for my Google Script. So what i want is for a number format output eliminating the special character

Comment: Plus this formula only works if all my data is a text value. Got an error- Function REGEXEXTRACT parameter 1 expects text values. But '0.07' is a number and cannot be coerced to a text. My data from above has a mix of < 0.03 and 0.03/ 0.04 things like that

Comment: @SairamSEKARAN it did convert it into text... answer updated **`VALUE`** added

Comment: player0: this function works. But it also converts empty cells from the source file to 0 in the importrange file. How to i make sure its left blank. The source file is a running file and keeps getting updated. So i might have to use something like "Sheet1!A1:A" but leave the empty cells as it is in the importrange file.

Comment: sure, try: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(
 IMPORTRANGE("ID", "Sheet2!A1:A")), "\d+.*"))), VALUE(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(
 IMPORTRANGE("ID", "Sheet2!A1:A")), "\d+.*"))),))`